# couldn't remove index.php from url

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter-3

I am using CodeIgnitor 3.0.0. I have read many question on same issue but neither seems to work for me, currently htaccess code is taken from CI docs (i have tried various .htaccess code from here given in different answers too) and have also checked the code with Rewritebase. This is my .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

i have also checked my config.php file many times as some answers suggested to do

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

and i have also checked if my write_mode in Xampp is on as well, it has

```
AllowOverride All
```

Do it have anything to do with default route ?

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'welcome';
```

if there is any other file required just tell me. I have already spent the day on it, any help would be appreciated 
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do like this in your codeigniter

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /project_name/

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

Comment: i have tried it before and now again but result is same :(
it says Object not found

Comment: Did you change this part RewriteBase /project_name/?

Comment: yes, don't know what's happening i have restarted xampp multiple times as well